# Segmentation fault when writing contents of dictionary to file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, dynamic-allocation, calloc

The code I am working on reads in a dictionary of 45430 words and then prints to the file all the other words in the dictionary contained within each word. I am just working on getting the file MyDictionary txt file read into the char array word[45430][30] and then printing this to the words-in-words txt file. I run into a seg fault at 44946 word when I do so, but in the same while loop I am also printing to the console and all words print out properly. Why is it I am getting this seg fault for writing to the file? And why is there no seg fault writing to the console?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>
//char ***alloc_array(int,int);

int main(void){
        FILE *fr; //declare file read file pointer
        FILE *fp; //declare file printed file pointer

        //char array to read in up to 30 chars
        char line[31];

        long numwords=45430; //number of words in dictionary
        int maxlength=31; // the longest string in dictionary (30 chars)
        long i; //counts up to 45430

        //allocate space for 45430 words at a max length of 30 chars (1 extra char for "\0")       
        char ***word = calloc(numwords, sizeof(char **));
        for(i = 0; i != numwords; i++) {
            word[i] = calloc(maxlength, sizeof(char *));
        }

        //Open MyDictionary.txt and determine if there is an error or not        
        fr = fopen ("MyDictionary.txt", "r");  // open the file for reading    

        if(fr==NULL){
               printf("\nError! opening input file");
               exit(1); //Program exits if file pointer returns NULL. 
        }

        //Open  words-within-words.txt and determine if there is an error or not        
        fp = fopen ("words-within-words.txt", "w");  // open the file for reading    
        if(fp==NULL){
               printf("\nError! opening output file");
               exit(1); //Program exits if file pointer returns NULL. 
        }

        int j=0; //counts to 30 for max length
        i=0;
        while(fgets(line, 40, fr) != NULL){ //get a line, up to 40 chars from fr and put first .  done if NULL 

            for(j=0;j<30;){
                word[i][j]=&line[j];
                j++;
            }
            j=0;
            printf("\n%s",word[i][j]); //print out each word of dictionary to console on its own line
            /*
            if((i>4 && i<8)||(i>45428)){
                fprintf(fp,"\nanalyze:word[i][0]=%s\tword[i][2]=%s\ti=%li",word[i][0],word[i][2],i+1);
            }
            */
            fprintf(fp,"%s",word[i][j]); //print out each word of dictionary to words-in-words on its own line
            i++;
        }  
        fclose(fr);  //close the files prior to exiting
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
} //main
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char ***word = calloc(numwords, sizeof(char **));
for(i = 0; i != numwords; i++) {
    word[i] = calloc(maxlength, sizeof(char *));
}
```

You've got one too many levels of indirection. You are storing a list of words. A word is a `char *`, so a list of words would be `char **`.

```
char **word = calloc(numwords, sizeof(char *));
for (i = 0; i != numwords; i++) {
    word[i] = calloc(maxlength, sizeof(char));
}
```

This will then necessitate changes to the rest of your code. You can get rid of `j` entirely. This:

```
for(j=0;j<30;){
    word[i][j]=&line[j];
    j++;
}
```

Becomes:

```
strcpy(word[i], line);
```

And this:

```
j=0;
printf("\n%s",word[i][j]);
fprintf(fp,"%s",word[i][j]);
i++;
```

Becomes:

```
printf("%s\n", word[i]);
fprintf(fp, "%s\n", word[i]);
```

Comment: For my assignment I actually need the form of word to be. word[num_words_in_dict][length_longest]. I believe the idea is so that it will be easier to find words within words once I learn how to print all of them to the file. Thanks though

Comment: Correct. The `strcpy()` however could overflow the destination as it's 10 bytes shorter than the source.

Answer (score 0):

'word' should be an array of pointers, so the right type is `char **`, not `char ***`.
Each entry in the array is a pointer to a buffer of characters:

```
char **word = (char **)calloc(numwords, sizeof(char *));
if (!word)
    // exit with error

for (i = 0; i != numwords; i++) {
     word[i] = (char *)calloc(maxlength, sizeof(char)); // just allocate 31 bytes
     if (!word[i])
         // exit with error
}
```

Then a read from file can be done like this:

```
for (i = 0; fgets(line, 40, fr); i++) {
    strncpy(word[i], line, maxlength);
    printf("word %d: %s\n", i, word[i]);
}
```

Comment: I wish I could use yours and Johns solutions they make perfect sense to me. However I need the format of word to be word[num_words_in_dict][length_longest]

Comment: you mean, you want to have a single block of memory that contains all your dictionary ? Why an array of strings is not suitable ?

Comment: I believe it is so that you can later try and find words within words by moving through each char of the word. I know I could do it otherwise but the instructions clearly state otherwise.

Comment: No, you have 45430 different words. Each word has a different length, up to 30 characters (31 bytes). There is no point to store them in one chunk (2D array). An array of strings is better already. And of course, there are data structures that are suited much better for dictionary allow all efficient searches and other operations.

Answer (score 0):

To have one chunk of memory do allocate like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  size_t n = 45430;
  size_t l = 30;

  char  (* words)[n][l + 1] = calloc(n, l + 1);
  if (NULL == words)
  {
     result = EXIT_FAILURE;
     perror("calloc() failed");
     goto lblExit;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    strncpy((*words)[i], "test", l);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    printf("%zu: '%s'\n", i, (*words)[i]);
  }

  free(words);

lblExit:

  return result;
}
```